# How to buy discounted single fares with an SL Access card

Tags: public-transport, stockholm

As far as I know and remember, if using an SL access card on the Stockholm tunnelbanan, a single fare can be bought by just using the card at the gate to enter. But how does that work if one is entitled to a reduced price because of young or old age? Does one have to use the vending machines to get the discount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you buy the card you can decide if it is gonna be for full or reduced price. It is also possible to change it in a vending machine or by talking to an agent in the subway or on the bus. It is not possible to do over the web.

Comment: Thanks, I should have guessed that it is that easy.